# Имплементация в Collections

Tags: java, коллекции, implementation

в чем разница?

```
ArrayList<E> arrayList = new ArrayList<E>(); 

List<E> arrayList = new ArrayList<E>(); // Map<E> map = new HashMap<>();
```

Как я понял, ArrayList имплементирует интерфейс List,

```
public class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E>
        implements List<E>, RandomAccess, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable
```

тогда в чем смысл использовать вторую запись, если ArrayList реализует больше методов и полей?

Answer (score 0):

Это делается согласно конвенции. Такая форма записи вам дает преимущества. Допустим вы создаете список в таком виде:

```
List<E> arrayList = new ArrayList<E>();
```

потом поработав с ним, оказывается, вам необходимо удалять множество значений из списка. Но arrayList для такого не подходит (он медленный при удалении объектов, ввиду внутренней реализации). Окей, не проблема. Вы берете переменную arrayList и ссылаете ее на LinkedList

```
arrayList=new LinkedList<>();
```

(не забыв перенести элементы). И LinkedList позволит вам эффективно удалять элементы из листа. При создании листа как arraylist - вы бы так не смогли сделать. То есть это намного удобней, вы создаете объект как Лист и в дальнейшем не паритесь о его реализации, вы просто знаете что это Лист. Вы к ней не привязаны - и можете манипулировать объектом, и в любой момент можете изменить его реализацию. Короче, прям реально ощутимых преимуществ это не дает, просто так удобней.

Comment: Можно сказать, что ArrayList реализует сам себя
 и по этому ему не доступны другие реализации?

Comment: ну фактически ArrayList это класс, а не интерфейс, поэтому не понятно что подразумевается под реализацией ArrayLista, но по сути, можно и так сказать

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо программировать на уровне интерфейсов, а не их реализаций.
Т.е необходимо делать
`List<E> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();`, а не `ArrayList<E> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();`
,`Map<K,V> map = new HashMap<>();`, а не `HashMap<K,V> map = new HashMap<>();`. Также делать и с параметрами у методов, это позволяет использовать все прелести полиморфизма.